# How to get the image in the clipboard with a J/Link method?

Tags: java, clipboard

The `Paste` will not give a return,just print the content of clipboard.It is hard to asign the result to a variable.I make a *.NET* method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139544/21532) to get the image in clipboard,but some platform cannot use *.NET*.So I expect a method based on *J/Link*.

Comment: If you look in the SETools source, you will find a way to do it with `NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[]`.  That is how the "pixel perfect" method works.  This is not an answer to your question, because you wanted a J/Link solution.

Comment: Maybe something like `First@First@NotebookImport[NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[], "Input"]`, but I have not checked this for robustness.  SETools should have a robust version.  This also doesn't verify that you actually have an image.

Comment: @Szabolcs Fun,this is my solution:``ToExpression[First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]],"InputText"]]]]``.I have to confess your version is better than my.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh,note your version cannot process [this graphics](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/31/58de7beb9a87e.jpg) whose `Head` is `Graphics` in clipboard.But my version can. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite ambitious to extract an image in an arbitrary format from the clipboard using only `JLink`.  This is because the code must anticipate variations such as vector vs. raster format, color models, encodings, and so on.  *Mathematica's* built-in image facilities do a lot of the heavy lifting for us, and I would encourage using a method based upon [ClipboardNotebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3081/142), or by means of [Paste](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Paste.html) into a temporary hidden notebook (both admittedly awkward methods).

Having said that, here is a quick-and-dirty *JLink* method to extract a rasterized version of a clipboard image via an intermediate *PNG* representation:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.Toolkit", AllowShortContext -> False];
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor", AllowShortContext -> False];
LoadJavaClass["javax.imageio.ImageIO", AllowShortContext -> False];

getClipboardImage[]:=
  JavaBlock @ Module[{clipboard, flavor, image, bytes}
  , clipboard = java`awt`Toolkit`getDefaultToolkit[] @ getSystemClipboard[]
  ; flavor = java`awt`datatransfer`DataFlavor`imageFlavor
  ; If[!clipboard@isDataFlavorAvailable[flavor], Return[$Failed]]
  ; image = clipboard @ getData[flavor]
  ; bytes = JavaNew["java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"]
  ; javax`imageio`ImageIO`write[image, "PNG", bytes]
  ; Mod[bytes @ toByteArray[], 256] // FromCharacterCode // ImportString[#, "PNG"]&
  ]
```

This code assumes that the clipboard image is represented in Java as a [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).  It would be possible to extend this to support other image types by various means, but those are outside the scope of the present response.

I have tested this successfully on Windows with the usual raster image formats on the clipboard: PNG, GIF, JPEG.  I am not in a position to test this code on MacOS or Linux.

Comment: Crazy,man.It's exactly what I want.;)And note my upon comment based on `ClipboardNotebook` maybe better than your link?